# Gradle task's doFirst() does not get executed first, but after task is done

Tags: java, gradle

I created a Gradle task in Java:

```
class TestTask extends Exec {

    public TestTask() {

        doLast(new Action<Object>(){
            @Override
            public void execute(Object task) {
                System.out.println("Should be last ");
            }
        });

        doFirst(new Action<Object>(){
            @Override
            public void execute(Object task) {
                System.out.println("Should be first ");
            }
        });

        commandLine("echo", "Should be between");
    }
}
```

Executing this task, I expect to get

```
Should be first
Should be between
Should be last
```

but instead I get

```
Should be between
Should be first
Should be last
```

I am in the process of converting a plugin from Groovy to Java, and in Groovy the processing order was as expected when defined like this:

```
task dofirsttest(type: Exec) {
    doFirst{
        println "Should be first"
    }
    doLast{
        println "Should be last"
    }
    commandLine "echo", "Should be between"
}
```

Is there something wrong with my task?

Answer (score 2):

`commandLine("echo", "Should be between");` is in the configuration phase of the task. So it will be executed first. Have a look at: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Comment: As I understand it, `commandline` only configures the task for later execution, just like other tasks. Otherwise I would see output during the configuration phase, e. g. on `gradle task` and no output during the execution phase.